# Applying different commands at different location

Tags: android, python, ubuntu

I am working in Ubuntu. 
I have a bunch of commands (say 10 commands like cmd1, cmd2, cmd3..............cmd10)

I want to write a python script, which can achieve the following:

It should traverse through the directory structure and apply a command
at particular directory path.
The location and the commands are already known to me.

Here is the example how, I want the script to operate.

```
/local/mnt/myspace/sample1$ cmd1
/local/mnt/myspace/sample2$ cmd2
/local/mnt/myspace$ cmd3
/local/mnt$cmd4
/local/mnt/myspace/sample9$ cmd 8
/local/mnt/myspace/sample3$ cmd10
```

can someone please help on this.

Comment: why Python? this is better suited to a shell like Bash. and why tagged android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use [`os.chdir(path)`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html).

Something like:

```
import os
from itertools import izip
paths = ('/local/mnt/myspace/sample1', '../sample2', 
         '../', '../', 'myspace/sample9/', '../sample3']
commands = (func1, func2, func3, func4, func5, func6)
for path, command in izip(paths, commands):
      os.chdir(path)
      command()
```

And just put each command in a function.

Edit: I thought it was different *Python* commands you wanted to run in different directories. If it's different external programs, use:

```
commands = (['cmd1', 'arg1'], ['cmd2', 'arg2'], ...)
for path, command in izip(paths, commands):
      os.chdir(path)
      subprocess.call(command)
```

No reason to use `Popen` and `wait` when this is specifically what `call` is for.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe something like this:

```
import subprocess
import os
jobs=[
    ('/local/mnt/myspace/sample1', 'cmd1'),
    ('/local/mnt/myspace/sample2', 'cmd2'),
    ('/local/mnt/myspace', 'cmd3'),
    ('/local/mnt', 'cmd4'),
    ('/local/mnt/myspace/sample9', 'cmd', '8'),
    ('/local/mnt/myspace/sample3', 'cmd10'),
]

for job in jobs:
    print "In", job[0], "executing", job[1:]
    os.chdir(job[0])
    subprocess.Popen(job[1:]).wait()
```

(just a quick shot)

Look how I have "abused" the apparent mistake at cmd 8 to show how to call programs which take parameters.

Comment: You can use `subprocess.call` instead of `subprocess.Popen` and `wait`. You would could even use the same 'abuse' :).

Answer (score 1):

```
import os

pathCommands = {r'C:\Windows':'dir', r'C:\test':'cd..' }

for path, command in pathCommands.items():
    os.chdir(path)
    os.system(command)
```

Comment: `os.system` is when you need to use features of the shell (bash, COMMAND.COM, whatever), not when you just need to launch an external program. For that, when you want to block till it's done, use `subprocess.call` as I've done in my answer.